# how to convert php heredoc to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, heredoc

How do I convert PHP HEREDOC to JavaScript variable. I have PHP variable with some special symbols.

php:

```
$text = <<<EOD
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOD;
```

to JavaScript:

```
var text = '<?php echo $text ?>';
```

Comment: And your question is? (@Hanky웃Panky We just have to wait a minute and all vampires will come :D)

Comment: I have some html code in php heredoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to convert a PHP value to a Javascript literal:

```
var text = <?php echo json_encode($text) ?>;
```

This works because JSON format is a subset of Javascript literal syntax. It will properly quote the strings and escape characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: Nice answer. This covers escaping single quotes in `$text` too.